# How do I make an image move according to text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pre element with a lot of text, and I have an image that I want to stay anchored below a keyword in the pre element

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
  pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: justify; font-family: comic sans ms;">        
    The image I want anchored should be right over <span id="here" style="text-decoration: underline;">here</span>.
    </pre>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you can add CSS but that you can't alter the HTML?

Comment: Is CSS `background-image` enough? That would certainly place the image underneath the text.

Comment: Sorry, I meant below, I edited the question now

Answer (score 0):

You can place a pseudo element relative to the span.

I'm not clear whether you want the image to be in amongst the text or to be above it (in the Z index sense) or how you would like to size it. Change the span:before settings as required.

Here's the basic idea:

```css
  pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
  span::before {
    content: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/150);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20vmin;
    height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: justify; font-family: comic sans ms;">        
    The image I want anchored should be right over <span id="here" style="text-decoration: underline;">here</span>.
    </pre>
```

You can give the span position relative and position the before either relative to that or absolutely in relation to that and also give it a higher z index if that is what is required.